# In which sense affine Grassmannian is "affine"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-langlands, affine-grassmannian

A pretty naïve question: Which meaning has the term "affine" in the notion of [affine Grassmanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Grassmannian). Especially, I do not see any immediate connection to the concept of an "affine scheme" in the classical sense, so seemingly the terminology arose from another concept. But which one? Is there a reasonable "justification" known for the choice of this name?

Comment: Surely it comes from affine Lie algebras and affine Lie groups, which act on the affine Grassmanian. In that case "affine" comes from the Weyl group being a group of affine transformations.

Comment: I'd agree that it's misleading terminology, if one does not know the context that @WillSawin mentions. That is, "affine" groups/algebras have non-finite Weyl groups, which, in many useful cases, still do have models that act by affine transformations on a plane (rather than on a sphere, as with finite Weyl groups).

Comment: Geometrically speaking, an affine Grassmannian is a subset of vertices (of fixed type) of an affine building. Just like an ordinary Grassmannian is a subset of vertices of a spherical building. The ordinary, Grassmannian has structure of a scheme. An affine Grassmannian, similarly, has structure of an ind-scheme.